# php SELECT with join but show data that is not joined

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 3 tables:  tbl_article, tbl_channel, tbl_published shown underneath.

tbl_article

```
articleID  title
1          lorum
2          ipsum
```

tbl_channel

```
channelID   channel
1           facebook
2           twitter
3           linkedin
```

tbl_published

```
publishedID     channelID   articleID
1               1           1
2               2           1
```

tbL_articles contains all the articles, tbl_channels all the channels an article can be published on and tbl_published shows all the channels the article CURRENTLY IS published on.

So, in my 3 tables above article 1 'lorum', is published on Facebook and Twitter.
But article 1 'lorum' is NOT published on Linkedin.

I know I can show all the channels article 1 is published on with JOINS, but  want to get ALL the channels article 1 is NOT published on, in this example that is only Linkedin.

I have been looking for an answer but I don't know hot to phrase this question and thus I can't find an answer.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your channel is NOT in published table

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_channel
WHERE tbl_channel.channelID NOT IN 
   (
       SELECT tbl_published.channelID
       FROM tbl_published 
       WHERE tbl_published.articleID = 1
   );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that gets all the entries in `tbl_published` for a channel and the article with the ID `1`.

```
SELECT c.*
       FROM tbl_channel c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM tbl_published p
                                WHERE p.articleid = 1
                                      AND p.channelid = c.channelid);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this for all articles, then use a `cross join` to generate all combinations and filter out the ones that exist:

```
select a.articleid, c.*
from tbl_article a cross join
     tbl_channel c left join
     tlb_published p
     on p.channelid = c.channelid and p.articleid = a.articleid
where p.channelid is null;
```

You can filter for one or more articles in the `where` clause as well.